# How do I get the current time in a different time zone without setting TZ variable

Tags: c, datetime, timezone, libc

How do I get the current time in a different time zone without setting tz variable (because I don't want to change my local time zone (IST)).

For example: I need different timezone time like (PST, EST,....).

Comment: do you need daylight savings, or do you want static zones?

Comment: i also need daylight savings time but right now i have only one input as a time zone like (PST,EST). so how can i calculate DST with different time zone.

Comment: There are complex issues to be resolved, including "how do you identify the current time zone and the other time zone", how do you know which time zone offset applies to each time zone at the given time, and so on.  Note that abbreviations like PST and EST are not unique worldwide, so they are ambiguous at best.  What happens if the correct time zone should be PDT but you think it is PST?  Such issues need to be resolved to come up with a reliable solution.

Comment: Also, which platform are you working on?  Some systems have more support than others.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use something like linux's time.h and then do post processing for your different time zones?

```
void linux_time_get
(
    os_time_t* p_time_seconds,
    os_time_us_t* p_time_microseconds
)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL); /* Second arg is timezone */
    if (p_time_seconds)
    {
        *p_time_seconds = tv.tv_sec;
    }
    if (p_time_microseconds)
    {
        *p_time_microseconds = tv.tv_usec;
    }
}
```

And then the caller of this function modifies 'p_time_seconds' and 'p_time_microseconds' according to which timezone you want to use?

Alternatively you could make a local variable for 'tz', to be parsed in as the second arg to the 'gettimeofday()' function.

Comment: thnk u bro...!!

Comment: No problem :) If this has helped you and answered your question, please up-vote and mark it as the answer!

Comment: how can we calculate same thing for DST(day light saving time) without change of TZ variable

Comment: Make another function to convert time to DST by adding a fixed value to the 'p_time_seconds' and' p_time_microseconds' variables.

Comment: but second parameter i have to pass            struct timezone {
               int tz_minuteswest;     /* minutes west of Greenwich */
               int tz_dsttime;         /* type of DST correction */
           }; but i don't have this information

Comment: From the manual: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html

"""
The use of the timezone structure is obsolete; the tz argument should normally be specified as NULL.
"""
So leave the timezone struct as NULL and then if you need to shift your timezone from what is outputted you can do so by writing a separate function.